# Generic vector class using unique_ptr follow up

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to implement a generic vector class using std::unique_ptr. This is my first time doing this with smart pointers so I know I am probably making stupid errors. I just do not understand these errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Vector, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(109): error C2676: binary '[': 'std::unique_ptr<T,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int,
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(105): note: while compiling class template member function 'Vector<int>::Vector(int,const T &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\main.cpp(19): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'Vector<int>::Vector(int,const T &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\main.cpp(14): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Vector<int>' being compiled
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(172): error C2676: binary '[': 'const std::unique_ptr<T,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int,
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(170): note: while compiling class template member function 'void Vector<int>::display(std::ostream &) const'
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(80): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void Vector<int>::display(std::ostream &) const' being compiled
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(182): error C2676: binary '[': 'const std::unique_ptr<T,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int,
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(178): note: while compiling class template member function 'int Vector<int>::get(int) const'
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\main.cpp(23): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'int Vector<int>::get(int) const' being compiled
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(190): error C2676: binary '[': 'std::unique_ptr<T,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int,
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(186): note: while compiling class template member function 'void Vector<int>::set(int,const T &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\main.cpp(22): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void Vector<int>::set(int,const T &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(225): error C2676: binary '[': 'std::unique_ptr<T,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int,
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(215): note: while compiling class template member function 'void Vector<int>::insert(int,T &&)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\main.cpp(30): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void Vector<int>::insert(int,T &&)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(225): error C2088: '[': illegal for class
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(227): error C2676: binary '[': 'std::unique_ptr<T,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int,
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(238): error C2676: binary '[': 'std::unique_ptr<T,std::default_delete<_Ty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=int,
1>            _Ty=int
1>        ]
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(232): note: while compiling class template member function 'void Vector<int>::remove(int)'
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\main.cpp(28): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void Vector<int>::remove(int)' being compiled
1>c:\dev\vector\vector\vector.h(238): error C2088: '[': illegal for class
1>Done building project "Vector.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

From what I gather I cannot use "[]" with unique ptr? Should I not use unique ptr then and use perhaps shared ptr?

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef Vector_h
#define Vector_h



template <class T>
class Vector {
private:

    static constexpr int initial_capacity = 100;

    // Instance variables
    int capacity = 0;
    int size = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<T> data = nullptr;

    void deepCopy(const Vector<T> &source) {
        capacity = source.size + initial_capacity;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.size; i++) {
            data[i] = source.data[i];
        }
        size = source.size;
    }

    void expandCapacity() {
        auto oldData = std::move(data);
        capacity *= 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            data[i] = oldData[i];
        }
    }

public:

    // Constructors
    Vector() = default;                                 // empty constructor
    Vector(int n, const T &value);                      // constructor
    Vector(Vector<T> const &vec);                       // copy constructor
    Vector<T>& operator=(Vector<T> const &rhs);         // assignment operator

    // Rule of 5
    Vector(Vector<T> &&move) noexcept;                  // move constructor
    Vector& operator=(Vector<T> &&move) noexcept;       // move assignment operator
    ~Vector();                                          // destructor

    // Overload operators
    T& operator[](int index);
    T const& operator[](int index) const;
    bool operator==(const Vector<T>&) const;

    //Vector<T>& operator+=(const Vector<T> &other) {
    //  Vector<T> newValue(size + other.size);

    //  std::copy(this->data, this->data + this->size, newValue.data);
    //  std::copy(other.data, other.data + other.size, newValue.data + this->size);

    //  newValue.swap(*this);
    //}

    friend Vector<T>& operator+(Vector<T> &source1, Vector<T> &source2) {
        int n = source1.getSize() + source2.getSize();
        static Vector<T> newSource(n,0);
        for (int i = 0; i < source1.size; i++) {
            newSource[i] = source1[i];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < source2.size; i++) {
            newSource[i + source1.getSize()] = source2[i];
        }

        return newSource;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &str, Vector<T> &data) {
        data.display(str);
        return str;
    }

    // Member functions
    void swap(Vector<T> &other) noexcept;
    void display(std::ostream &str) const;
    int getSize() const { return size; }
    int getCapacity() const { return capacity; }
    bool empty() const { return size == 0; }
    void clear() { size = 0; }
    T get(int index) const;
    void set(int index, const T &value);
    void set(int index, T &&value);
    void insert(int index, const T &value); 
    void insert(int index, T &&value);
    void remove(int index);
    void push_back(const T &value);
    void pop_back();

};



template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int n, const T &value) {
    capacity = (n > initial_capacity) ? n : initial_capacity;
    size = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data[i] = value;
    }
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(Vector<T> const &vec) {
    deepCopy(vec);
}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(Vector<T> &&move) noexcept {
    move.swap(*this);
}



#endif /* Vector_h */
```

Here is the main.cpp file:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <ostream>
#include "Vector.h"


int main() {

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////// VECTOR //////////////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    Vector<int> nullVector;                        // Declare an empty Vector
    assert(nullVector.getSize() == 0);                 // Make sure its size is 0
    assert(nullVector.empty());                    // Make sure the vector is empty
    assert(nullVector.getCapacity() == 100);          // Make sure its capacity is greater than 0

    Vector<int> source(20, 0);                      // Declare a 20-element zero Vector
    assert(source.getSize() == 20);                 // Make sure its size is 20
    for (int i = 0; i < source.getSize(); i++) {
        source.set(i, i);
        assert(source.get(i) == i);                 // Make sure the i-th element has value i
    }






    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can see this question is getting downvoted. Can anyone explain why so I can make the proper edits?

Comment: Please reduce this massive amount of code to a [mcve].

Comment: @JesperJuhl Okay, but as I understand. I thought I was suppose to include all the code I have on StackOverFlow for context?

Comment: No. Not *all* the code. You are supposed to create a *new* [mcve] that still reproduces the problem and then post *that*, rather than your original code.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I see but I do not see how I could do that for this case since I need to show the class I built where I create the unique_ptr.

Comment: There is *lots* of code that's not related to the problem that you could easily cut out in the example posted here.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Is that better now?

Comment: Are swap, display, operator+, operator=, operator==, etc required to reproduce the error? I suspect not.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx `static Vector<T> newSource(n,0);` --  Your usage of `static` here means this won't be a very generic vector once it is used in a multi-threaded app, rather a broken `Vector` class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie should I make it auto then instead of static?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx -- If `operator +` is supposed to concatenate one vector onto another, then you should be returning a *brand new* vector with the concatentated results, not a reference to a static vector.  In addition, if that is the case `operator +` concatenates vectors, then you really should be implementing `operator +=` first, returning `*this`, and then implement `operator +` in terms of `operator +=` (basically a one or two line function).  If you want an example of a sequence container that behaves as I've described, look no further than `std::string` and how those operators behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understood the error message correctly when you assumed that

> From what I gather I cannot use `[]` with unique ptr?

To be precise, you should not use `[]` with `unique_ptr<T>` when `T` is not an array type. You can use `operator[]` on `unique_ptr<T[]>`, though. The point of `unique_ptr` is the implied ownership tracking and automatic deletion when a `unique_ptr` owning an object is destructed. It does so with `operator delete`. This operator *must not be used* with arrays allocated using `new T[count]`, just with single objects allocated with `new T(constructor parameters)`. On the other hand, a special case of `unique_ptr`, spelled as `unique_ptr<T[]>`, uses `delete[]` on its object. So unsing `unique_ptr<T[]>` instead of `unique_ptr<T>` fixes both the problem of not having `[]` as well as unsing the wrong deletion function.

Comment: Okay, that is what I thought but when I change it to std::unique_ptr<T[]> I get this error that I do not understand:

Comment: '1>------ Build started: Project: Vector, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int & __thiscall Vector<int>::operator[](int)" (??A?$Vector@H@@QAEAAHH@Z) referenced in function "class Vector<int> & __cdecl operator+(class Vector<int> &,class Vector<int> &)" (??H@YAAAV?$Vector@H@@AAV0@0@Z)
1>C:\Dev\Vector\Debug\Vector.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "Vector.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========='

Comment: That error means that you declared but did not implement `T& Vector<T>::operator[](int)` and was used in the implementation of the plus operator.

Comment: I get an error which I beleive is due to the capacity not being set for the std::unique_ptr<T[]>. Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: `unique_ptr` ist not about managing a dynamic array with capacity and size - that's what `vector` is supposed to do. To use `unique_ptr`, you have to obtain a memory block yourself (e.g. by using `new int[capacity]`) and setting the `unique_ptr` to point there. Since C++14, you also might use `make_unique<int[]>(200)` to wrap allocation and constructing of a `unique_ptr` object into one step.

Comment: While I do think that your original problem (trying to use `unique_ptr<T>` to hold a pointer to an array) is worth being discussed on stackoverflow, as the concept of having pointers to arrays and pointers to singletons as separate type is something new with `unique_ptr`, the follow-up questions in the comments disgress from the original question. Different problems should be different questions, BUT I am afraid that the simple linker error for an undefined function, or not allocating data for a pointer are likely to get downvoted a lot, especially if you can't manage to trim the code...

Comment: ... to something like 20 to 30 lines that point out your problem, as a minimal complete and verifiable example.